# How to convert json response to an array?

Tags: java, json, api, rest

I want values in json response to get listed instead of showing as comma separated single line response. Below is my part of code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(DaoIntegration.getCustomSearchBody().getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " +
        con.getResponseCode());
} else {
    content = (InputStream) con.getInputStream();
    result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(content, "UTF-8");
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    String MemberResponse = jsonObject.get("MemberResponse").toString();
    String[] members = MemberResponse.split(",");
    System.out.println("MemberResponse: " + members);
}
```

what am getting now is in this format:

MemberResponse: { "AnniversaryDate": null, "EmirateResidence": null, "ReferralCode": "ERXEN0B1NJ", "Email": "abc@gmail.com", "TotalPointsLapsed": "0" }

I want the format to be like in below image:

[image]

Comment: you can convert jsonobject to an hashmap with object mapper. Then from the hashmap convert to whichever form as required.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and beautify your json and print? Please make sure you add the necessary jackson.core as dependency.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonObject);
```